# Display tag is not showing table headers even the basic.show.header has been set to true

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I am using `Display tag` library for some pagination and sorting. It is working fine so far but I need to show the table headers even there is no record. I've set the `basic.show.header` property to true according to the documentation but still I am seeing `Nothing found to display` message. Please take a look at the code if I am doing something wrong.

```
<display:table id="data" name="intgList" requestURI="/integration/viewIntegration" class="fieldLabelCell" pagesize="4">
    <display:setProperty name="basic.show.header" value="true" />
    <display:column property="lob" title="Line of Business" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="insuredName" title="Insured" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns"/>
    <display:column property="custPhone" title="Customer Phone" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="policyNumber" title="Policy #" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="createdDate" title="E-Sign Created Date" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="custEmail" title="Customer Email" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="esignNumDocs" title="# of E-Sign Documents" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using a wrong property. I should have used `<display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />` instead.